# Java OO static ultility method help!

Tags: java, methods, static, instance

I recently did a method in the User class which looks like this;

```
  public static boolean checkUN(String username) {
  boolean check = false;
  ResultSet rs;
  String dbQuery;
  SQLController db = new SQLController();
  db.setUp();
  dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE User_name ='" + username + "'";
  try {
   db.setUp();
   rs = db.readRequest(dbQuery);
   if (rs.next()) {
    check = true;
   }
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
  db.terminate();
  return check;
 }
```

I intended it to be a validation check before the User is able to continue to the next step of registration.

When I showed it to the teacher, she said that it would be ok, as im using it as a ultility method. However, she changed her mind later on, saying that I should change this to an instance method, then creating a new User object to do the validation.

Which way is more effective?

```
user.checkUsername(jTextUN.getText());
```

and the instance way 
(assuming I changed the method, removing static and the input parameter);

```
User user = new User();
user.setUsername(jTextUN.getText());
user.checkUsername();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

I would probably create some sort of UserValidator class and create an instance of that to contain your method.

Answer (score 2):

First off, I don't like the solution that involves creating a new `User` object and then calling `checkUsername()` on it for several reasons:

- If no valid user exists with a given username, you shouldn't have any `User` object representing that user... because they don't exist. This isn't a hard and fast rule, since sometimes you might want a `User` object representing a user you're about to create or some such, but here I find it unnatural.
- It violates expectations about what data objects can do. Creating a `new User()` and then having `checkUsername()` return different values depending on what username that user is given would be surprising.

Now, I know you're in a class and so this may go beyond what you're learning, but to go even further:

Neither solution seems very good to me because both tightly couple any code that uses them to the database, making that code difficult to test.

The general solution to this is to wrap the code that would make components that use it difficult to test in an interface, something like this:

```
public interface UserService {
  boolean checkUsername(String username);
  ...
}
```

Then you can create an implementation of `UserService` that talks to the database, and classes that need to use that code can have an implementation of it injected in their constructors:

```
public class UserServiceClient {
  private final UserService userService;

  public UserServiceClient(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
  }

  ...
}
```

This is the principle of dependency injection. In addition to just making your code more flexible, it allows you to provide fake implementations of `UserService` for testing. If you want to test what happens in a certain class when `checkUsername` returns `true` and what happens when it returns `false`, you can just use fake implementations that always return `true` or always return `false`. You don't have to worry about setting up database connections or ensuring that the right data is present or ensuring that the database state is properly reset after a test, and equally importantly a test is far faster when it doesn't have to do database communication.

Another thing you might want to do that falls somewhere in between the two approaches would be to have a `User` object that stores data on a user (but can't communicate with the database or any such thing itself) and to put a method like this in your `UserService`:

```
User getUser(String username);
```

This method would return the `User` object for the user with the given username if one existed and `null` otherwise. You could also implement `checkUsername` as just

```
return getUser(username) != null;
```

Comment: I think this pattern should be used to create an implementation of a Database interface with methods open(), close(), isOpened(), query(), etc, because one day you could change you database adapter and probably you don't want to change the rest of your classes that uses a database. If you apply this technique to get information about users, as you said, is good for testing purposes but you will probably test the methods only one time, when you create them. So using a dependency injection design will probably augment you number of classes without any sense. Look to my answer.

Comment: ..continue
That class (UserHelper) is using a Database implementation (created with DatabaseFactory.createDatabase() method), that overrides open(), close(), etc methods. Think about that.

Comment: @GagleKas: No... your answer involves tightly coupling code to the database when it doesn't need to be. A dependency injection solution with the code that (in production) talks to a database hidden behind an interface makes it _much_ easier to change how you implement that service later, because you just need to create a new implementation and wire that into the clients that need it. You don't need to change any existing classes. I'm not really sure what you're saying about a Database interface, since JDBC, JPA etc. already provide database abstractions.

Comment: Well, yes, it's what you've said, clients using an interface to use a database.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the second way is more extensible and more intuitive (in terms of if you want to change things later on), so I'd recommend it. But the first way solves the problem directly, and if the concept of a "user" won't be extended later (with new methods), then either one should be fine.